# Stuck bathtub stem

Tags: plumbing

Tried wd-40, liquid wrench, engine degreaser, stem socket wrench, heat, hammer and chisel.  Nothing works.  Cold side came off.  Looks like some kind of sealant was applied.  Corners of stem socket stripped.

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible left hand thread

Comment: Damn... real big pipe wrench and be prepared to buy a new stem. Be careful, it is possible to tweak the valve-body/pipes in the wall. You might start figuring out how to open up that wall (maybe from the back side?) to replace the whole unit...

Answer (score 1):

I second (or third) the pipe wrench solution.  However, I would add that you should be prepared for worst case scenario, which includes damaging the valve, and possible the solder that connects the piping to the valve.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I think a pipe wrench is in order. Nothing else will grab what's left of the valve. Even if you do get it out finding a replacement stem might be tough. Maybe time to update to a new valve. Good luck.